# How to display subtitles with an flv file in a web page?

Tags: flv, flvplayback, subtitle

I've created subtitles for a video in mp4 format, that i would like to put online, as an FLV file.
Is it possible to have the subtitles played along with the flv file without integrating them into the video images, so keeping them in srt format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, using JW flv player :

1. convert your .srt file to an xml file (php code below)
2. then add a variable "captions" pointing to your xml file:

s0.addVariable("captions","path/to/subtitles.xml");

live example [here](http://www.ergonomie-web.be/placer-lutilisateur-au-centre-paul-bennett-ideo-video/)

```
// script to convert multi-line srt caption files to new-format (02-05-08) tt XML caption files
$use_cdata_tags = true;
$debug_output = true;

// the directory to write the new files in
// it must exist, be writeable, and be outside of the directory that is being scanned
$new_directory = '../temp/';

/////////////////////////////////// no user configuration below this \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

// get filename or scan directory if it's a directory
$filename = (isset($_GET["filename"])) ? strval($_GET["filename"]) : "./";

// read each file into an array
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("$filename");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
{

// debug('Filename', $file); exit;
// debug('Ext', substr(strtolower($file), (strlen($file) - 4), 4));// exit;

// debug - only use test file
// if($file == '.\multi-line_test_file.srt')

  // check for .srt extension
  if(substr(strtolower($file), (strlen($file) - 4), 4) == '.srt')
  {
    $ttxml     = '';
    $full_line = '';

    if($file_array = file($file))
    {
      // write tt , head, and div elements for the new file
     $ttxml .= "";
      $ttxml .= "\n";
      $ttxml .= "  \n";
      $ttxml .= "  \n";
      $ttxml .= "  \n";
      $ttxml .= "    \n";

      foreach($file_array as $line)
      {
        $line = rtrim($line);

// debug('Line', $line);

        // get begin and end
        //                00  :  00  :  32  ,   000   -->   00  :  00  :  37  ,   000
        if(preg_match('/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d) --> (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d)/', $line, $match))
        {
          $begin = $match[1] . ":" . $match[2] . ":" . $match[3] . "." . $match[4];
          $end   = $match[5] . ":" . $match[6] . ":" . $match[7] . "." . $match[8];
          $full_line = '';
        }
        // if the next line is not blank, get the text
        elseif($line != '')
        {
          if($full_line != '')
          {
            $full_line .= '
' . $line;
          }
          else
          {
            $full_line .= $line;
          }
        }

        // if the next line is blank, write the paragraph
        if($line == '')
        {
          // write new paragraph
          //                 Nothing is going on.
          if($use_cdata_tags)
          {
            $ttxml .= "      \n";
          }
          else
          {
            $ttxml .= "      " . $full_line . "\n";
          }

// debug('Text', $line);
// debug('ttxml', $ttxml); exit;

          $full_line = '';
        }
      }

// write ending tags
$ttxml .= " \n";
$ttxml .= " \n";
$ttxml .= "\n";

      // write new file
      $new_file = $new_directory . substr($file, 0, (strlen($file) - 4)) . '.xml';
      $fh = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die('Can\'t open: ' . $new_file);
      fwrite($fh, $ttxml) or die('Can\'t write to: ' . $new_file);
      fclose($fh);
    }
  }
}


function debug($title, $value)
{
  global $debug_output;

  if ($debug_output)
  {
    print "";
    if (is_array($value))
    {
      print $title . ":\n";
      print_r($value);
    }
    else
    {
      print $title . ": " . $value;
    }
    print "\n";
  }
}

?>
```